# Perl: HTTPS website login

Tags: perl, https, login-script

I am using the following code:

```
my $login = "https://steamcommunity.com/login/home/?goto=market%2F";
my $username = "USR";
my $password = "PASS";
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new());
$mech->get($login);
$mech->form_name('loginForm');
$mech->field(login => $username);
$mech->field(passwd => $password);
$mech->click();
```

To log into a website, unfortunately it is not working, any trouble shooting help would be really appreciated. You can visit the website with the login url.

EDIT, the modules im using.

```
use JSON::XS;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTTP::Cookies;
use LWP::Simple;
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Comment: Can you post your complete script please? There are lots of reasons why your code might not be working - e.g. not including the correct modules via the 'use' keyword.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logging into a HTTPS website with perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23722525/logging-into-a-https-website-with-perl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Steam's Subscriber Agreement](http://store.steampowered.com/subscriber_agreement/) states:

> You may not use Cheats, automation software (bots), mods, hacks, or any other unauthorized third-party software, to modify or automate any Subscription Marketplace process.

They also provide an [API](http://steamcommunity.com/dev).

These reduce the incentive to help you manipulate their web site processes. You are better off figuring out how to use the API. If the API doesn't provide you a means to do what you want, it may be best to avoid doing it.

Comment: Sorry i didn't realize :/ Ive given in anyway thanks for the response Ill check out the API.